# machine learning vs learning theory vs both?

Tags: discussion, tags

This has been bothering me for a bit -- we have a machine learning tag and a learning theory tag.  Now given that this site is a theory site, every ML question should also be a Learning Theory question in some sense.  On the other hand, the focus of learning theory is different than of all of machine learning, but I'm not sure if this distinction is needed on this site.

Should we have one tag or use both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a third tag called [[lg.learning](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lg.learning)].  I am not familiar with machine learning or learning theory, and I am fine if relevant people are not confused by these tags, but I just wanted to draw attention to the existence of the third tag.

(I should have realized the other two tags existed before [asking for an edit of the tag wiki of [lg.learning]](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/what-should-the-tag-wikis-contain/360#360).)

Comment: thanks - it also seems that the learning-theory tag is getting auto-converted to lg.learning...

Answer (score 2):

Learning theory (and correct me if I'm wrong) appears to be the narrower, and more well defined notion (say, everything that appears in COLT/ALT). Whereas a question on (say) consensus clustering or generative models for clustering problems, or even learning Gaussians, might not fit under 'learning-theory' but is easily placed under 'machine learning'.

Comment: Learning theory certainly has it's own focuses -- but i wonder if this distinction is too fine for this site.  For example, should http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/517/complexity-of-fitting-models-to-data be tagged as learning theory?

Comment: I don't know. If learning-theory is defined as COLT+ALT, I'd say no. If learning theory is defined as ML with proofs, then yes :). but this is really a question about statistics.

Comment: Okay - your idea sounds reasonable. To be consistent, I will remove the ML tag from http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/pac-learning-boolean-conjunctions