# Retagging the Warren Buffett question?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Martin Pál's question on the [Warren Buffett problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/the-warren-buffett-problem) is currently tagged with gt.game-theory, machine-learning and online-learning. Should the gt.game-theory tag instead be lg.learning-theory ? See also [this related discussion](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/machine-learning-vs-learning-theory-vs-both) on machine-learning vs learning-theory.

Comment: IMHO, it would be nice if all learning questions have the lg.learning-theory tag, but I am not sure if we need to remove the gt.game-theory tag.

Comment: I think @Suresh means machine-learning to lg.learning-theory, no? But the lg.learning / machine-learning / learning-theory, etc. tags are a complete mess...

Comment: @Suresh: It seems like a question about effective Hausdorff dimension to me, instead of either of those. Not-necessarily-fair reward functions that are oblivious to the past, and the user starts with a finite initial budget and tries to maximize profit.  This sounds a lot like gales and martingales, in which case there is a lot of literature.  I haven't posted there yet because I was away, and I don't know if I'm reading it right.

Comment: I have no opinion about [machine-learning] vs [learning-theory], but why is the proposal of adding the [learning-theory] tag to the question coupled with the removal of the [gt.game-theory] tag?

Comment: because I don't think game-theory is a relevant tag for this question

Comment: (Reposting a comment with a minor edit because my previous comment disappeared during the [datacenter relocation](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/1383845452/datacenter-move-engage).)  I have no opinion about whether this question is related to game theory or not, either, but addition of [lg.learning-theory] to this question and removal of [gt.game-theory] are two different things which should not be coupled in decision making.  In other words, this is not a retag request.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I'm new here. I agree the game-theory is not an appropriate tag and I've removed it. I've added lg.learning (lg.learning-theory doesn't seem to be an existing tag).

Answer (score 0):

I think this question should not be tagged gt.game-theory but instead as Suresh suggests, lg.learning-theory is the right tag here.

(I don't think Suresh intended to suggest merging gt.game-theory into lg.learning-theory, although the question could be read that way.)

Comment: that's correct. sorry for the terse comments - have been busy at FOCS.