# Replacing the [advice] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

In the past the [`[advice]`](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice) tag has been used for requesting advice (i.e. confused with [advice-request] tag).

Peter [suggested](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/adding-tag-wikis/657#657) replacing [advice] with some other tag. Should we replace [advice] with some other tag and make [advice] a synonym to [`[advice-request]`](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice-request)? If the answer is positive, what should be the new tag?

I copy the suggestions here:

- [non-uniform]
- Multiple tags? advice-Karp-Lipton ... quantum-advice ... advice-(fillinblank)

Another possible replacement:

- advice-(complexity)

Comment: Are we resolved on this issue ? namely, shall we go with Peter's suggestion ? I can set up the merges etc in that case

Comment: @Suresh: It seems so, everyone seems to be happy with Peter's suggestion and it has already 5 votes. Could you please merge [advice] to [advice-and-nonuniformity]?

Comment: In this case, I am not sure if it is good to make [advice] a synonym for [advice-and-nonuniformity].  But now that the synonym has been made, I think that it is better to see if this avoids the confusion.  If we see questions asking for advice incorrectly tagged as [advice-and-nonuniformity], probably we should remove the synonym (but removing the synonym will invalidate the link to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice).

Comment: @Suresh: I have written a tag wiki for [advice]. Now that it is merged, it seems that the tag wiki is lost :(

Comment: @Sadeq: Seems like that. :(  Moderator can extract the content and copy it to the tag wiki for the new tag [advice-and-nonuniformity], I hope?

Comment: @Sadeq: I think you can still find it under recent wiki-tag changes in moderator tools. Take a look at [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/posts/3021/revisions)

Comment: @Kaveh: Thanks! Oddly, I cannot change the new merged tag wiki anymore. @Suresh: Could you please copy the old tag wiki to the merged one?

Comment: @Sadeq: I think it takes sometime for the site to update the list of top users of the new one, you will be able to edit it when it is updated.

Comment: @Kaveh: Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Sorry Sadeq: I didn't realize this would happen. Let me see if I can fix the edits

Comment: changes have been made.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is [advice-and-nonuniformity]. I also really like Tsuyoshi's suggestion.

Comment: assuming we go with one, I prefer this to Sadeq's 'advice-string', because this tag is more informative.

Comment: I also like this one, but I am not sure if we need the "and" in the middle. [advice-nonuniformity] and [advice-nonuniform] (or [nonuniform-advice]) seem good to me.

Comment: @Kaveh: Omitting “and” is acceptable to me, but I do not see any reason to do so.  Adding “and” makes the meaning clearer even without reading the tag wiki.  Moreover, [nonuniform-advice] looks like “the advice that is nonuniform,” which is pretty tautological.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I wrote that meaning *nonuniform/advice*. I don't know the effect of using / in tag names. update: I just tested it, the system removes /.

Comment: @Kaveh: I know what you meant, and that is why I wrote “[nonuniform-advice] _looks like_ ….”

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the tag [advice](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice) should be renamed.  How about [computation-with-advice]?

*Added*: Should we have two separate tags for computation with advice and for nonuniform computation, or one tag?  If two, I think that [computation-with-advice] is a reasonable name to replace the current tag [advice].  If one, I will second [Peter’s proposal](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/666/replacing-the-advice-tag/672#672) [advice-and-nonuniformity].  I do not have an opinion which is better.

Comment: In my opinion one tag is better (they are very close and having two tags can cause confusion) and I like Peter's suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

non-uniform is ok, but it's not precise enough, is it ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [advice-string]. It is short, and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea so I don't know how good it is:

> make [advice] a synonym for [nonuniform].

Comment: I cannot see how this is supposed to prevent the misuse of the [advice] tag.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: if someone misuses the [advice] tag, the system will automatically replace it with the [nonuniform] tag and the OP will notice this and hopefully will edit the tags to correct it. I also think synonym are shown at the bottom of drop down menu (because no post is tagged with them) so the [advice-request] will be the top tag shown when someone types "advice". But as I said I don't know if this is good idea.

Comment: In my experience, new users are too ignorant to notice such tag replacements. And experienced users know what the [advice] tag means. Hence, this approach does not seem to solve the problem.